# Dynamically added script tags don't execute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script tag in my HTML document like this:

```
<script SRC="story_content/user.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I want to add another script tag right after it dynamically using javascript, so I wrote the code like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  addSources();
};


function addSources(){

  const selectUserJs = document.querySelector('[src="story_content/user.js"]');
  selectUserJs.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<script SRC="../../../modules/speaks/speakDictate.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>');

}
```

This code adds the new script tag to the HTML document successfully but the script doesn't execute!!!? What? What I'm missing? And how to fix this?

Comment: is there a reason you can't just use `document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src="../../../modules/speaks/speakDictate.js";`

Comment: I want to add the script right after the existing script tag... I don't think I can use appendChild?!

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert it as an element or self-terminate the tag:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  addSources();
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
};


function addSources(){
  const selectUserJs = document.querySelector('[src="story_content/user.js"]');
  selectUserJs.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',document.createElement('script')).src="../../../modules/speaks/speakDictate.js";

  selectUserJs.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<script SRC="../../../modules/speaks/speakDictate.js" TYPE="text/javascript"/>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="story_content/user.js"></script>
```